# Explaining NAT Tranversal C++?

Tags: firewall, p2p, nat, dht, kademlia

I have created an P2P application which is FULLY decentralized and is using a Kademlia algorithm to make it so. This has been tested on the local network and it completely successful.

I heard about UDP Hole Punching, however hole punching requires the peer to know about the clients IP and vice versa, however as said due to design it is impossible. As it would require each peer to keep on asking the supernode\server for new arrivals and keep them assigned and so naturally it is not too dependable especially if the supernode is down.

Due to the design of the algorithm 1 peer does not know the other peers IP address so I need 1 peer to completely open a port up for PUBLIC to be able to connect to, how can I do this, in Windows? could someone perhaps also give me suitable links that might give me a direction?

It would be preferable (but not absolute) if they use c++\c as example

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to change your architecture a little. There is no other way for NAT traversal unless you configure your NAT for port forwarding (I think you don't want this). You might need to implement three layers:

- Lower layer 1: it knows about IP addresses and ports and can solve problems like hole punching or dealing with servers (which could be down but first you have no choice and second you can add alternatives for connectivity).
- Layer 2: implements special naming, addressing and location services for your solution (instead of using IP addresses).
- Upper layer 3: implements your p2p solution using lower layer naming and location services.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to examine your design. If it needs 100% connectivity between all nodes (without relays) it's probably going to fail under IPv4 since not all NATs are traversable. And possibly under IPv6 due to stateful firewalls.

Now, for the nat traversal: A solution for DHT-assisted NAT traversal is for NATed nodes to have a rendezvous node.

To keep the UDP NAT mappings open it has to regularly ping that rendezvous node.

Additionally it has to announce the address of the rendezvous point on the DHT, e.g. under `hash("rendezvous" + node ID)` or simply on its reachable neighbor nodes.

The rendezvous node can then act as coordination point for hole punching.

This does not require any special "supernode", just other (possibly multiple, thus eliminating the SPOF) nodes in the network that are not NATed and can assist.

Additional mechanisms such as UPnP IGP, NAT-PMP, [PCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6887) and ultimately instructing users to forward the needed ports can also help to reduce the need for nat traversal.

Answer (score 0):

> Due to the design of the algorithm 1 peer does not know the other peers IP address so I need 1 peer to completely open a port up for PUBLIC to be able to connect to

First of all this will only work for Full cone NAT. For other types of NAT that public IP:Port you open will only work for specific destination. In your case you don't know the destination so it's impossible.

In case of full cone NAT, you send a packet to a random address with low TTL value so that the packet drops in the middle and doesn't reach that address. If it reaches than that address's NAT might block you. If you do this then a port will be opened for anybody to send you a packet. You need to keep sending packets after some short interval for that port to be remained open. Here is a problem that you can't choose which port to open in the NAT. The NAT will assign you a free port on its own.

Finally I don't see any point doing any of the above if peers can't exchange their IP information with each other. You should use a signalling protocol like SIP or XMPP to exchange IP information between peers.

To learn more about NATs please read this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323230/how-to-connect-to-an-open-tcp-port-on-client-machine-from-an-unknown-server/31382269#31382269)